# Calculating time remaining in org-mode

Tags: org-mode

I am using org-mode to track effort. I would like to be able to see, in column view, the sum total of time remaining on a project (that is, Effort - CLOCKSUM).

I haven't had much luck so far. [This](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.emacs.orgmode/61459/focus=61555) provides some code but requires a lot of dependencies I haven't been able to track down.

There is a very old discussion of how to use custom formulas for columns in org-mode [here](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-orgmode/2009-03/msg00350.html). However, perhaps this pertains to org tables, rather than column view, since I can't get even the example in the email to work:

```
:COLUMNS:  %25ITEM %2d{`(,(or curval 0) 0)} %f{`(,(or curval 0) 0)}
```

%2fd{`(,(+ $f $d) 0)}

More generally, something like %f{FUBAR} returns the value of property 'f' regardless of what code I replace FUBAR with.